# How to convert String[] that contains numbers to int[] in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, casting

What I got it's this instruction that gives me back a `String[]` object:

```
string.trim().split(" ");
```

The content using `Arrays.asList(string.trim().split(" "))` it's something like:
`[4, 3, 2, 5, -10, 23, 30, 40, -3, 30]`

So its content is made up by numbers. What I want it's to convert the `String[]` object to an `int[]` one. How can I do that without parsing every single string to a int?

Comment: "How can I do that without parsing every single string to a int?" you can't. At some point it will need to be parsed (explicitly or implicitly). If you want to simplify your code you can use something like `int[] intArr = Stream.of(strArray).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();`

Comment: What you can do is to Create a function to mannually covert String to int but that would be worse

Comment: I was ambiguous sorry. What I meant was to not use directly a for loop

Comment: You are asking for magic.  Whether you write one or it is implicit in stream processing, a loop will be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *kind of* do it without loops but you only get a `List<Integer>` not an `int[]`.

```
private static class IntegerAdapter extends AbstractList<Integer> implements List<Integer> {
    private final List<String> theList;

    public IntegerAdapter(List<String> strings) {
        this.theList = strings;
    }

    public IntegerAdapter(String[] strings) {
        this(Arrays.asList(strings));
    }

    @Override
    public Integer get(int index) {
        return Integer.parseInt(theList.get(index));
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return theList.size();
    }
}

public void test(String[] args) {
    String test = "4 3 2 5 -10 23 30 40 -3 30";
    String[] split = test.split(" ");
    IntegerAdapter adapter = new IntegerAdapter(split);
    // Look ma! No loops :)
    System.out.println(adapter.get(4));
}
```